# What triggers the information bar in internet explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, information-bar

What causes the IE information bar to pop up and block 'active content' on a webpage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Personal experience**

From my experience as a developer this information bar is triggered most times for me when having active content such as JavaScript executed from a local file that I open with Internet Explorer.

To disable the Local Machine Zone(LMZ) restriction (for running active content from your local computer): In Internet Explorer open the Internet Options. On the Advanced tab find the Security section of the list and check "Allow active content to run in files on My Computer". (not recommended)

**Microsoft Windows documentation**

> When will I see the Information bar?
>
> If Internet Explorer is still using
>   its original settings, you'll see the
>   Information bar in the following
>   circumstances:
>
> - If a website tries to install an ActiveX control on your computer or
>     run an ActiveX control in an unsafe
>     manner.
> - If a website tries to open a pop-up window.
> - If a website tries to download a file to your computer.
> - If a website tries to run active content on your computer.
> - If your security settings are below recommended levels.
> - If you access an intranet webpage, but have not turned on intranet
>     address checking. For more
>     information, see Changing intranet
>     security settings.
> - If you started Internet Explorer with add-ons disabled.
> - If you need to install an updated ActiveX control or add-on program.
> - The webpage address can be displayed with native language letters
>     or symbols but you don't have the
>     language installed.

*Source:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Internet-Explorer-Information-bar-frequently-asked-questions*

Answer (score 1):

In the most general terms, the Information Bar appears whenever IE (as the user agent) automatically makes a security decision for you (the user).

For example: the website wanted to run an Active X control, but IE decided not to let it run; the website wanted to open a pop-up Window, but IE decided it wasn't something you wanted to see; etc.  Stefan has a good list in his answer.

The Information Bar is the user's notification of the action, and an entry point for the users to override the decision.